# Overloading abstract generic methods in C#

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, abstract-methods

I'm trying to implement a generic abstract method with a type constraint, then Implement it multiple times using different specified types.

```
public abstract class Ability
{
   public abstract void BindToStation<T>(T station) where T : Station;
}

public class DashAbility : Ability
{
    public override void BindToStation<NavStation>(NavStation station){ }
    public override void BindToStation<CannonStation>(CannonStation station){ }
}
```

But I get an error which says the method has already been defined with the same paramater types.

I'm guessing that the compiler treats any generic paramater as the same in terms of the method signature, so these two methods look the same to it.

Still though, I'm wondering if theres a way to have generic method overloading using specific types.. ?

Comment: C# does not support template specialization.  You can't do that.

Comment: How would that make it generic? If you have a generic method is because it will work for any generic type that suits the constraint. Having one method per type is the same as not having a generic method at all

Comment: Looks like your `Station` implementation is not generic at all, otherwise you wouldn't need a method per derived type. Feels like you're doing something wrong :)

Comment: The underlying problem I see is that you want to combine two implementations of `Ability` into one class. If there are actually two implementations then there should be two classes.

Comment: It's not two implementations- it's two types that Ability could be **binded** to. BindToStation is a method to do custom configuration for a specific station.
I already have a solution where I have one BindToStation(Station s) method and do type checking **INSIDE** that method, but that seems a little roundabout- thought this would be a more modular solution

Comment: Perhaps `Ability` should be an interface? I begin to think this is an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/353610).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you want, but you can try an approach like this:

```
interface IBindableTo<T> where T : Station
{
    void BindToStation(T station);
}

abstract class Ability
{
    public abstract void BindToStation<T>(T station) where T : Station;
}

class DashAbility : Ability, IBindableTo<NavStation>, IBindableTo<CannonStation>
{
    public override void BindToStation<T>(T station)
    {
        if (this is IBindableTo<T> binnder)
        {
            binnder.BindToStation(station);
            return;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void IBindableTo<NavStation>.BindToStation(NavStation station)
    {
        ...
    }

    void IBindableTo<CannonStation>.BindToStation(CannonStation station)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't recommend runtime type checking which in turn may throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't support specialization in that way, and neither does C++ easily when you want to specialize on runtime type.

But you can use polymorphism, so you can use double-dispatch:

```
public abstract class Station {
    internal abstract void DashBindToStation();
}

public class NavStation : Station {
    internal override void DashBindToStation() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CannonStation : Station {
    internal override void DashBindToStation() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public abstract class Ability {
    public abstract void BindToStation(Station station);
}

public class DashAbility : Ability {
    public override void BindToStation(Station station) {
        station.DashBindToStation();
    }
}
```

Another possibility with C# is to use runtime dispatching using `dynamic`:

```
public abstract class Station {
}

public class NavStation : Station {
}

public class CannonStation : Station {
}

public abstract class Ability {
    public abstract void BindToStation(Station station);
}

public class DashAbility : Ability {
    public void BindToStation(NavStation station) {
    }
    public void BindToStation(CannonStation station) {
    }

    public override void BindToStation(Station station) {
        BindToStation((dynamic)station);
    }
}
```